# Array explode has empty value for html tag <li> how to not include that value

Tags: php, html

I have a random id generator which could be anywhere from 1 to x number of ids

```
$ranGen = "IDENTIFIER | c0402347-8b93-49e4-991b-8213ea2921b1| e8087fc5-ded7-43ab-858d-127fe23f90bc|" ;
```

I'm trying to go through each value and present it as an un-ordered list

```
<?php
$ranGen = "IDENTIFIER | c0402347-8b93-49e4-991b-8213ea2921b1| e8087fc5-ded7-43ab-858d-127fe23f90bc|" ;
$array =  explode("|", $ranGen);
echo '<ul>' ;
foreach ($array as $value) {
echo '<li>' . trim($value) . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

I get the following results

```
<ul>
<li>IDENTIFIER </li>
<li> c0402347-8b93-49e4-991b-8213ea2921b1 </li>
<li> e8087fc5-ded7-43ab-858d-127fe23f90bc </li>
<li></li>
```

I do not want the last blank list - is there a way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the value before you echo:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if( trim($value) != '') {
        echo '<li>' . trim($value) . '</li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: This works and is very simple.  The id generator will always produce the | no matter how many created. Again thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Check if the value is empty within the loop
2. Ignore the last part (if *all* of your input strings have that superfluous part at the end)

[See this example:](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d75f8865b7847986130997e4468c600fb28a3954)

```
<?php
$ranGen = "IDENTIFIER | c0402347-8b93-49e4-991b-8213ea2921b1| e8087fc5-ded7-43ab-858d-127fe23f90bc|" ;
$array =  explode("|", $ranGen);
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($array as $value) {
    // Option 1
    if (trim($value) !== "") {
        echo '<li>' . trim($value) . '</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';

// Option 2
$array =  explode("|", $ranGen, -1);
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo '<li>' . trim($value) . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line : `echo '<li>' . trim($value) . '</li>';`

with this: `echo trim($value) ? '<li>' . trim($value) . '</li>' : null;`

Answer (score 0):

Just filter it out:

```
$array =  array_filter(explode("|", $ranGen));
```